# c++ how to construct variant efficiently?

Tags: c++, variant

may I know if there is more efficient way of constructing below variant?

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
class Person{
public:
    Person(std::string name, int age, std::string school)
    :name_(name), age_(age){}

private:
    std::string name_;
    int age_;

};
class Dummy1{};
class Dummy2{};
using PersonVariant = std::variant<Person, Dummy2, Dummy1>;
int main() {
    Person person("jack", 10, "school");
    PersonVariant pv(person); // does this involve an uneccessary copy?
}
```

The construct seems involve an unnecessary copy.

Comment: How should a compiler know that the copy is _unnecessary_?

Answer (score 4):

Most efficient way is to use in-place constructor:

```
PersonVariant pv{std::in_place_type<Person>, "jack", 10, "school"};
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> PersonVariant pv(person); // does this involve an uneccessary copy?
> ```

Yes.  `person` is an lvalue so a copy will be made to construct the `Person` object in the variant.  You have a couple of options to make this better.  The simplest fix is to use

```
PersonVariant pv(Person("jack", 10, "school"));
```

Which will construct a temporary object that will get moved into `pv`.

You can also use variants in place construction to pass the values to construct the `Person` object directly inside the variant like

```
PersonVariant pv(std::in_place_type<Person>, "jack", 10, "school");
```

There is no moving or copy of a `Person` in this case and at most you would have a move or copy of the parameters to construct the `Person` object but you have that cost no matter what so this can be considered the most efficient way to do this.

---

For completeness sake you could also use

```
Person person("jack", 10, "school");
PersonVariant pv(std::move(person));
```

which will force `person` to be moved into the variant like `PersonVariant pv(Person("jack", 10, "school"));` does but now `person` is a moved from object and you can only reuse it as it is essentially an empty object (in the context of the values of the members).